# Can't get from CUSTOMERS table by CUST

Tags: priority-web-sdk

I'm trying to get data from CUSTOMERS table by CUST field, but I get a 404 error. Here is the requesting endpoint:
/CUSTOMERS(CUST=1217)

I priority web there is no problem to get customer by this id…

Anyone can help?

Comment: I think it would be better to add more info about the table.

Comment: Its plain CUSTOMERS table

Answer (score 1):

After you get the customer with $filter, you'll know its id ("CUSTNAME"), so you'll be able to do all the updates needed using it instead of "CUST"

Answer (score 0):

You can use $filter in order to get the requested customer by CUST
Try the following: 
`/CUSTOMERS?$filter=CUST eq 1217`

More information and examples can be found in the API documentation on github
https://prioritysoftware.github.io/restapi/

Comment: But if I want to update the record:
PATCH /CUSTOMERS(CUST=1217)/CUSTPERSONNEL_SUBFORM(PHONE=3022)
I can't do this with filter...

Comment: CUST is the auto unique field of CUSTOMERS, if you want to perform an update operation you have to use the key field which is CUSTNAME.

Answer (score 0):

can you try using /CUSTOMERS('1217') instead of  /CUSTOMERS(CUST=1217)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a record by its key, and this is key is **not** a complex key (it has only one column in it) you just use brackets and the value of the key, you don't mention its name. 
If the key data type is string => you surround it with single quote 
**but** if it is Integer => without quotes.
In your case:

/CUSTOMERS(1217)